# Logout from terminal in Debian 8.2

Tags: debian, gnome, session, debian-jessie

I'm trying to log out from terminal. On Debian 8.3 I can use `gnome-session-quit` to achieve this, but on 8.2 there is no `gnome-session-quit`. I know that I can do `pkill -u username` to achieve this but I want to do the same thing (send Dbus messages) and log out.

How can I do that on version 8.2, or is there any other script that would do the same?

Comment: Looks like a [`dbus-send` encantation explained here](http://askubuntu.com/a/15796) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can logout using the following command:

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u {username}
```

or

```
sudo pkill -u {username}
```